# jQuery document delete key

Tags: javascript, jquery

I attached the delete key to document so when delete key is pressed, div gets removed. However when i'm inside a textarea, i don't want this behavior. The delete key inside textarea should only delete text and not affect the document and deleting the div. The following is not working;

```
$(document).keyup(function() {
    if (e.which == 46) {
        $('div').remove()
    }
})
```

Check http://jsfiddle.net/a3Vdu/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A check against the type of element that triggered the event will work.

```
if (/input|textarea/i.test(e.target.tagName)) {
     return;   
}
```

Here's it added to your example
http://jsfiddle.net/JY46t/

Comment: very nice solution. Takes care of both inputs and textarea.

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind a handler to the textarea to capture the event before it bubbles to the document. Write a similar function for your texarea:

```
$("#mytextarea").keyup(function(e) {}, false);
```

The inclusion of 'false' prevents event bubbling.